# Python Pandas pivot and map values

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, pivot

Let's say I have a dataframe that has columns: id1, id2, valueType, value.

First, I want to pivot the dataframe to append columns for the different possible value types (valueType.unique() ?). Then, for each value, I want to map it into the correct valueType column at the row with the corresponding id1, id2. I figure I would also have to account for the fact that the new pivoted columns would not necessarily be equal in length (i.e some valueType appear more often than others) so I'd have to fill those in with NaN before. What's the best approach to this? I'm guessing I would use pivot() and set_index() on the dataframe?

---

Input `df`

```
    id1 id2 valuetype  value
0     1   a    height      5
1     1   a     width      4
2     1   a    length      3
3     1   b    height      6
4     1   b     width      5
5     1   c    length      4
6     2   a    height      3
7     2   a     width      6
8     2   b    height      7
9     2   b    length      8
10    2   c    height      9
11    2   c     width      5
```

Expected Output

```
   id1 id2  height  length  width
0    1   a     5.0     3.0    4.0
1    1   b     6.0     NaN    5.0
2    1   c     NaN     4.0    NaN
3    2   a     3.0     NaN    6.0
4    2   b     7.0     8.0    NaN
5    2   c     9.0     NaN    5.0
```

Comment: it is better search your question in google before asking ..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pivot_table`

```
In [401]: (df.pivot_table(index=['id1', 'id2'], columns='valuetype', values='value')
             .reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1))
Out[401]:
   id1 id2  height  length  width
0    1   a     5.0     3.0    4.0
1    1   b     6.0     NaN    5.0
2    1   c     NaN     4.0    NaN
3    2   a     3.0     NaN    6.0
4    2   b     7.0     8.0    NaN
5    2   c     9.0     NaN    5.0
```

Or, Use `groupby`

```
In [404]: (df.groupby(['id1', 'id2', 'valuetype'])['value'].sum().unstack()
             .reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1))
Out[404]:
   id1 id2  height  length  width
0    1   a     5.0     3.0    4.0
1    1   b     6.0     NaN    5.0
2    1   c     NaN     4.0    NaN
3    2   a     3.0     NaN    6.0
4    2   b     7.0     8.0    NaN
5    2   c     9.0     NaN    5.0
```

Or, use `set_index`

```
In [414]: (df.set_index(['id1', 'id2', 'valuetype'])['value'].unstack()
             .reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1))
Out[414]:
   id1 id2  height  length  width
0    1   a     5.0     3.0    4.0
1    1   b     6.0     NaN    5.0
2    1   c     NaN     4.0    NaN
3    2   a     3.0     NaN    6.0
4    2   b     7.0     8.0    NaN
5    2   c     9.0     NaN    5.0
```